# Create alert in azure monitor using logged metric

Tags: python, azure, sdk

I am new to Azure ML. I would like to know if the metrics I logged in my experiment can be used to create an alert in the azure monitor. For example, if my logged metric is "Alert required", then start the alert, and if it is "No alert required". Can I do that? If so what are the steps I need to follow.

Many Thanks,
Sruthy

Answer (score 0):

You can use any resource in your Azure subscription that supports metrics. To determine whether a resource supports metrics, go to its menu in the Azure portal and verify that there's a **Metrics** option in the **Monitoring** section of the menu.

[image]

To create an alert rule you can go ahead and create a rule in azure monitor and select scope and add your subscription, RG, and your metric

[image]

Here is the complete information about metrics in [ML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/monitor-resource-reference#activity-log) you can have a look at it and here is the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/tutorial-metrics) on how to create metrics.

[image]

Comment: Thanks SaiSakethGuduru-MT.I will try to work on it and will let you know

Comment: Hi @SaiSakethGuduru-MT , when I look into the metrics I can only see options with in Runs, model, resource etc. I cannot select any metrics Iogged in my machine learning experiment. Am I missing something?